# Filter NSDictionary from NSArray

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I have One  NSArray That contains NSDictionary Object with keys{"name","age","weight"}
where the key name is NSString ,age is NSInteger ,weight is float Value

I need to filter the NSArray with the following conditions 
 1.name contains 'abc'
 2.age below 18
 3.weight less than 50

Answer will be Appreciated

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[c] %@ AND SELF.age.integerValue <= %d AND SELF.weight.floatValue < %f", @"abc", 18, 50.];

Answer (score 0):

This will work but is not elegant at all.

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dic in myArray){

int age = [[dic objectForKey:@"age"]intValue];

     if (age < 18){

        float weight = [[dic objectForKey:@"weight"]floatValue];
        if (float < 50){

        string name = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        if (![string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [filteredArray addObject:dic];
         }

        }
     }
```

}

The other elegant solution is to use the enumeration block and predicates to check your dictionary contents, but I'm not comfortable enough in objective-C to do that.